# C++ 2D growing array like MATLAB

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I have read some posts about dynamic growing arrays in C, but I can't see how to create a 2D growing array (like in MATLAB).

I have a function to construct an array for some image processing, but I don't know what will be the size of this array (cols and rows). How can I create this?

I read something about malloc and realloc. These functions are portable or useful for this problem.

EDIT: SOLVED, using the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), a C++ linear algebra library.

Comment: Look for a library that's designed for matrix analysis.  C++ is much more general purpose, and nothing like that is included in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is with pointers

```
int nrows = 10;
int ncols = 5;

double* matrix = new double[mrows*ncols];
```

And then you can access it as if it's a 2D array [like](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order).

So if you want `matrix[row][col]`, you'd do

```
int offset = row*ncols+col;
double value = matrix[offset];
```

Also, if you want the comfort of Matlab like matrixes in C++, look into [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: He is looking for a solution with dynamic resizing.

Comment: I thought his "dynamic" was create a 2D array of unknown size at compile time? I think I just misread it. Regardless, Armadillo is probably what he is looking for then. It's designed to be a matlab -esq matrix library for C++.

Comment: I'm using armadillo, but i can't resize a arma::mat variable .. i use the reshape method but this can only resize the rows size if i try to resize the cols size i have an error:" run-time error: Mat::operator(): out of bounds" ..

Comment: Hmm. that's odd. I just tried it and it definitely works. You should post your code, as getting arma::mat is a better solution IMHO.

Comment: finally i found the error.. was a silly mistake... with armadillo this works flawlessly ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing image processing, you might want to use the [matrix](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#Mat) and array types from [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/).

Answer (score 0):

By growing an array like Matlab, I'm assuming you mean doing things like:

```
mat = [mat; col]
```

You can resize a matrix in C++, but not with a clean syntax like the one above.

For example, you can use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` to represent your matrix.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat;
```

Then to add a column:

```
for (int i=0; i<mat.size(); i++) mat[i].push_back(col[i]);
```

or to add a row

```
mat.push_back(row); // row is a std::vector<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have a standard matrix class per-se.  I think there were too many different uses of such a class that made a one-size-fit all solution impossible.  There is an example and discussion in Stroustrup's book (*[The C++ Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C++_Programming_Language)* (Third Edition)) as to a simple implementation for a numerical matrix.

However, for image processing it's much better to use an existing library.

You might have a look at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/).  I've used it before and found it quick and well documented.

If you are on an AMD machine I know there is an optimised library for image processing from AMD, the Framewave project [Framewave Project](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/Libraries/framewave/Pages/default.aspx).

Also, if you are used to MATLAB style code then you may want to look at [it++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/current/).
I think the project aim is for it to be as similar to MATLAB as possible.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for OpenCV, especially useful if you are doing image analysis, as it abstracts the underlying data type (GRAYSCALE, RGB, etc.).